# How to center large text with image?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar that displays an icon and some text aligned. This sidebar is **resizable** and sometimes text and icon don't fit in the same line.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/UEk5b/1/) shows an example. Blue button shows how it looks like when the line fits and orange button shows what happens when the text is too long.

My goal is to make it look like this when the line is too long:

[image]

It is text should stay at rigth side of the image vertically centered with it. No problem if I have to change HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 70px;

ul span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul img {
    vertical-align: middle;
     margin: 0 0 0 -70px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ogofun/5/edit#html,live

Answer (score 4):

@Ivan; you can write like this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/UEk5b/15/

```
a, a:visited {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:table;
}
ul li a span {
    display: inline-block;
    width:102px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

`display:table` is not work in IE7 & below.

**Edit**

check this without `display:table` 
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/UEk5b/19/

Answer (score -1):

What you need is exactly described by html table elements:

```
<div id="resizable">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="ajax-page">
        <table><tr><td valign="middle">
          <img src="http://bit.ly/mRkUDB" alt="" width="60px" height="60px"/>
        </td><td valign="middle">
          <span>This is a test</span>
        </td></tr></table>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="ajax-page">
        <table><tr><td valign="middle">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/o7Elfp" alt="" width="60px" height="60px"/>
        </td><td valign="middle">
        <span>This is another larger test</span>
        </td></tr></table>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

although you still might want different representation with different CSS styles or at low widths, in which case using tables might be a bad idea.

Comment: This is invalid html - you cannot nest a table inside a list or link.